# Parallax effect issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, scrolltop

I'm experimenting some parallax effects. I have 5 boxes in my `HTML` that should move with a parallax effect. My issue is when I scroll the window all `div` don't move, however in the console the javascript seems to work well. I can't find where the problem comes from.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var pixels = $(document).scrollTop();

  $('div.box-1').css('top', pixels * -0.5);
  $('div.box-2').css('top', pixels * -0.25);
  $('div.box-4').css('top', pixels * 0.25);
  $('div.box-5').css('top', pixels * 0.5);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 3000px;
  margin: 300px auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

div.box {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

div.box-1 {
  background: red;
}

div.box-2 {
  background: orange;
}

div.box-3 {
  background: yellow;
}

div.box-4 {
  background: green;
}

div.box-5 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
<div class="box box-4"></div>
<div class="box box-5"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
```

Comment: Add to `div.box`: `position: absolute` and replace `$(document).scrollTop();` to `window.scrollY;`

Comment: Thank you! With position absolute it works great. However I still don't understand why I need the absolute position to make it work.

Comment: You need `position: absolute` becouse in default `relative` position not working top, right, bottom and left properties.